# InstallSchema not running even though module is not installed

Tags: magento2, module, database

I searched all over and don't see anyone with the same issue.

Below are steps I tried to solve this with no success

- I deleted the module from `setup_module` table.
- I don't see any errors in var/log/debug I don't see the log below, I do see the log from registration.php I put in
- It works for the other plugin I have under BB/StoreSchedule/Setup

I tried running the commands below:

- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- php bin/magento cache:clean
- I looked over my code for typos 50+ times
- I did not see the log from the InstallSchema in the log file.

Please any suggestions!

I am running Magento ver. 2.3.2

I am running on a mac using https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento as my dev environment

Running in the following mode

```
app@c98698704947:~/html$ php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
Current application mode: default. (Note: Environment variables may override this value.)
```

InstallSchema.php

```
<?php

namespace BB\CustomerGroup\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
   */
  public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
  {
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/debug.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info('TEST GOT HERE');

    $setup->startSetup();
    $table = $setup->getTable('customer_group');
    $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
      $table,
      'zip_codes',
      [
        'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'length' => 255,
        'nullable' => true,
        'default' => '',
        'comment' => 'Zip codes covered by this customer group'
      ]
    );
    $setup->endSetup();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Magento Stack Exchange. Could you please tell me what is your Magento version?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I am using Magento ver. 2.3.2. I'll add to the question

Comment: did you see the "TEST GOT HERE"  write in your installschema in  the log file?

Comment: @aravind. No I did not see the log. I put another log in the register file and that I saw.

Comment: I think You need to add that field in customer_group using upgradeschema..As that table is already created..So custom attributes should be added using upgradeschema

Comment: Can you confirm me that the module not installing is BB_CustomerGroup ?

Comment: @aravind I tried doing UpgradeSchema also and not even getting it to log out.

Comment: @Taschert I can confirm the module is getting installed as it is making it into the setup_module table

Answer (score 0):

First You Need To Change the Mode Default to Developer Mode.

After This InstallSchema.php That shown Below

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module_name\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface ;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class InstallSchema implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface
{

    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup,ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        if (!$installer->tableExists('table_name')) {
            $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
                $installer->getTable('table_name')
            )

                ->addColumn(
                    'zip_codes',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    255,
                    ['nullable => false'],
                    'Zip Code'
                );

            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

            $installer->getConnection()->addIndex(
                $installer->getTable('table_name'),
                $setup->getIdxName(
                    $installer->getTable('table_name'),
                    ['zip_codes'],
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT
                ),
                ['zip_codes'],
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT
            );
        }
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

> **Note** :: First Delete from Setup_module Tabel then Run Commna **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** Because the installschema run's one time at the installtion of the module